# Give extended notice period even if only bank staff?

Tags: resignation, contracts, notice-period

I have recently handed in my notice at work. I was told by my manager that I was on a contract so we agreed for 4 weeks notice, but I have discovered that I am only bank staff.

Do I still have to give the full 4-week period despite that I am only bank staff?

Comment: Depends on what the difference between bank staff and contractors is, what the terms of your employment are, and what jurisdiction and employment law applies.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, and Bank staff you can give a week notice and contract you can give a month.

Comment: @HorusKol I don't think she can really change, they agreed on a certain length. If the duration is not illegal for some reasons, then all what she can do is ask, but the manager has the right to refuse.

Comment: Well, what does your employment contract / service agreement / whatever say? You must have signed some paper(s) when you started. That's what matters.

Answer (score 8):

> we agreed for 4 weeks notice

Apparently, you just gave 4 weeks notice.

If you want to now give less, read through your contract and learn what you are required to do. Then talk with your boss and explain that you have changed your mind after you learned that you are just Bank staff.

(In the future, learn what you are required to do *before* you agree to do something else.)

Comment: Yes, first step is to *read the contract* to be 100% clear on what was agreed, and proceed after that.

Answer (score 4):

Your notice period is usually set out in your contract. If you agreed 4 weeks and your contract says 2, then it's a different question alltogether (which I encourage you to ask if that's the case).

Since you agreed on 4 weeks it doesn't matter what type of staff you are; that's the agreement. So, no, it should not be possible to change the notice period now.